# Write WPF output to image file

Tags: wpf

Is there a way I can write the output of WPF say a canvas to a image file, jpg or the like.

I want to use WPF to create a background for me as I want to use the
BitmapEffects for a rectangle and also radius the corners.

I want to use the bitmap in a webpage.

Is this possible?

Malcolm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a blog post all about this [here](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/how-to-save-xaml-as-an-image/). Here's the code from the article:

```
   Rect rect = new Rect(canvas.RenderSize);
   RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
     (int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
   rtb.Render(canvas);
   //encode as PNG
   BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
   pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

   //save to memory stream
   System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

   pngEncoder.Save(ms);
   ms.Close();
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("logo.png", ms.ToArray());
   Console.WriteLine("Done");
```